# Jquery datepicker doesn't show

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

This is sample code. On load i can see dateofbirth changing to  08-06-1990 but on clicking the textbox the datepicker is not shown. The layout.cshtml contains following

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js"></script>
```

and i can see they are loaded in firebug.I have removed the EditorFor and have instead 
used  just of testing. Any idea.

```
@model SMS.Model.Student

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#DateofBirth').val("08-06-1990");
        $('#DateofBirth').datepicker();
    });
</script>


<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Student</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RegistrationNo)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RegistrationNo)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RegistrationNo)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateofBirth)
        </div>

        <input  id="DateofBirth" value="07-06-1990" />

        <p>
            <input  type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: I don't see a closing </script> tag. Could that just be a typo in your example?

Comment: @Mark There was one, it was just indented wrong so didn't show up in the code block.

Comment: Its not the friendliest editor for adding code, I have discovered.

Comment: i can see the closing </script> tag there in example as well.

Comment: Are you also including the jqueryui css and images that are required? I'm also not seeing a type attribute for your datepicker input. type="text"

Comment: @Rishikesh the question has been edited to fix it.

Comment: It would be helpful if you add the rendered HTML instead of the template. it must be something in the HTML since it seems to be working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/JHB25/

Comment: @Mark The css reference was missing,now i added in layout.cshtml  @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css") which loads all the jquery ui css n i added type="text" too. Just now i noticed in firebug that there is an error saying "TypeError: $("#DateofBirth").datepicker is not a function" but i can see the jquery ui js file is loaded.

Comment: this is the rendered html                                        <label for="DateofBirth">DateofBirth</label>
</div>
<input id="DateofBirth" class="valid" type="text" value="07-06-1990">, but the error message says the datepicker is not a function so seems to be something else. I too checked on jsfiddle and it worked fine there.

Comment: Shot in the dark but are you using a custom jqueryui build, if so its possible that you didn't include the datepicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works now. I noticed that my layout.cshtml had

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
 @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

in the body section and i was explicitly referencing the jquery and jquery ui using  loading the the jquery file twice causing this issue.
I removed this from header

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js"></script>
```

and moved

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

to header and added jqueryui to the header. It works perfectly.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
```

Comment: I just spent 2 hours looking for a solution to this same problem until I finally stumbled upon your answer. Do you know how to add a link to a css stylesheet that will make the datepicker look different than the rest of my page?

Comment: I figured it out. I added `<link href="../../Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` above the `@Scripts.Render` lines.